# 'netcat -e' not relaying stdout

Tags: scripting, python, netcat, nc, backdoor

I'm using netcat to create a backdoor running a python script with the following command:

```
netcat -l -p 1234 -e 'python /script.py'
```

then I'm connecting to the backdoor with another shell using:

```
netcat localhost 1234
```

script.py is a simple loop that reads input, saves it to a file, and then prints it back. Now whatever I write in the second shell goes to the script and is successfully saved to a file. However, I don't see the output of the script on the second shell. I tried both the `print` and `sys.stdout.write`  methods of python and both seem to fail. I don't know why the output is relayed back to the second shell if I use this:

```
netcat localhost 1234 /bin/bash
```

But not with my script. I'm obviously missing something important. Here is my script:

```
import sys

while 1:
    kbInput = sys.stdin.readline()
    sys.stdout.write( 'Input: '+kbInput)
    f  = open("output.txt", "w")
    f.write(kbInput)
    f.close()
    print
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your writes to stdout are being buffered by python, and only written  when the buffer is full. There are 2 simple fixes:

1. Add the `-u` option to your python command to ask for unbuffered output (`'python -u /script.py'`).
2. Alternatively, flush the output after each write. In your example, after the line `sys.stdout.write( 'Input: '+kbInput)` add the line:

   ```
   sys.stdout.flush()
   ```

Comment: Omg finally. At some point I assumed it was something like that but I used `close()` which ended up causing an error. Thanks a bunch!